# Would I use a one-tailed paired-sample t- test on this?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, anova, t-test, manova, mathematica

I am doing an assignment that tests whether acceptance and commitment therapy is beneficial for social anxiety disorder.
With an experimental and controlled group.
I just need to know what test I would use out of t-test, ANOVA’s or chi-squared.
And the details of which one applies.
I’m thinking would be a one-tailed paired-sample t-test as there is one IV at two levels, and scores were within groups.
Pls help me it’s due in 48 hours

Comment: How do you measure `social anxiety disorder`?

Answer (score 0):

May you provide your dataset? I think if there are some groups, just go with ANOVA, while the result comes to significant, you can do the posthoc test to observe what kind of variables that significantly different between groups.

Just use t-test if you have two groups, while more than two, go with ANOVA, I suppose.